# python print to stdout getting lost on failing cluster jobs

Tags: python, io, output, stdout, stderr

I have a python code which I'm running on a computer cluster.  The default output (`stdout`, from `print`) gets lost when the code fails (or is canceled, etc).  It also doesn't appear in the output file when I call it immediately after the corresponding portion of code is called.

The error output (`stderr`) however, is printed when the job fails.  If I recall correctly, in c++ you can `flush` streams to make sure that output stuck in a buffer somewhere is actually printed.  Is there an analog for python?  How can I make sure to get this output, ASAP?

---

a schematic representation of my code

```
for it in somerange:
    print "Iteration", it       # This appears much later in stdout
    f = open(filename[it], 'w')
    f.write('stuff')
    f.close                     # file appears when it is closed
    otherStuff()
```

After a few iterations, I will have numerous output files (from `filename`), but no output in my `stdout` file.  If the function `otherStuff()` were to cause a crash (etc), output *Will* appear in my `stderr` file - but still nothing in my `stdout` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so `print` goes to [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.9/library/sys.html) which is a [file object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects), for which you can use the `flush()` command.  So the correct answer is to add `flush()` calls when needed, i.e.

```
import sys
...
for it in somerange:
    print "Iteration", it       # This appears much later in stdout
    sys.stdout.flush()
    f = open(filename[it], 'w')
    f.write('stuff')
    f.close                     # file appears when it is closed
    otherStuff()
```